# Como fazer consultas dentro de uma matriz em Java?

Tags: java

O problema pede a criação de um programa que leia o nome, cpf, e-mail e telefone de 10 pessoas. Em seguida, disponibilizar 4 opções de consulta (1-Por nome, 2-Por CPF, 3-Por e-mail e 4-Por telefone). Por exemplo, se o usuário escolher a opção 2, a consulta deverá solicitar um CPF e, com base nele, deverá imprimir os
dados do cliente que tenha este CPF. O programa deve informar caso não encontre nenhum cliente com o dado informado. Use uma matriz 10 x 4 para representar os dados.

O problema é que compila certo, pede as informações, informa o menu, mas quando insiro por exemplo um nome para consultar, não aparece nada. Qual é o problema?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de dados da matriz
        Scanner lm = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de dados do menu
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de nome
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de cpf
        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de email
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de telefone


        String m[][] = new String [10][4];
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe o nome, CPF, e-mail e telefone da " + (i+1) + "ª pessoa:");
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                m[i][j] = ler.nextLine();
            }
        }


            System.out.println("Opções de consulta:");
            System.out.println("|1| - Consultar por nome");
            System.out.println("|2| - Consultar por CPF");
            System.out.println("|3| - Consultar por e-mail");
            System.out.println("|4| - Consultar por telefone");
            int menu = lm.nextInt();


            switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Insira o nome:");
                String nome = n.nextLine();
                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                    if (nome == m[i][1]) {
                        System.out.println(m[i][1]);
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Insira o CPF:");
                String cpf = c.next();
                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                    if (cpf == m[i][2]) {
                        System.out.println(m[i][2]);

                    }
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Insira o e-mail:");
                String email = e.next();
                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                    if (email == m[i][3]) {
                        System.out.println(m[i][3]);
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Insira o telefone:");
                String telefone = t.next();
                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                    if (telefone == m[i][4]) {
                        System.out.println(m[i][4]);
                    }
                }
            break;

            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Comparação entre Strings;**

O problema principal é que vc está fazendo a comparação com `==`. A comparação entre Strings deve ser feita com `.equals` que faz a comparação por valor e não por referência.
Suas comparações dentro do `if` devem ficar assim: `m[i][1].equals(nome)`

**2) Laço `FOR`**

O seu laço for não tem um critério de parada praticamente: `for (i = 0; i < 0; i++)`. Da forma que está escrita, ele só iria parar quando i for menor do que
0, mas i já começa em 0, portanto ele irá acrescentar uma unidade até o infinito ou estourar alguma exceção. Tome cuidado com isso.

O correto seguindo sua lógica seria: `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.

**3) Index da Matriz**

Em Java, as estruturas começam em 0. Ou seja, se vc tem uma matriz 2x2 as posições que vc poderá acessar são: **0x0, 0x1, 1x0 e 1x1**. Portanto para que vc não receba um código de erro, coloque as posições corretas ao acessar as posições da sua matriz;

Com esses pontos, vamos englobar tudo isso no seu código. Coloquei como era antes comentado e como deveria ser para que vc possa comparar:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de dados da matriz
        Scanner lm = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de dados do menu
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de nome
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de cpf
        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de email
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in); //leitura de telefone


        String m[][] = new String[10][4];
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe o nome, CPF, e-mail e telefone da " + (i + 1) + "ª pessoa:");
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                m[i][j] = ler.nextLine();
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Opções de consulta:");
        System.out.println("|1| - Consultar por nome");
        System.out.println("|2| - Consultar por CPF");
        System.out.println("|3| - Consultar por e-mail");
        System.out.println("|4| - Consultar por telefone");
        int menu = lm.nextInt();


        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Insira o nome:");
                String nome = n.nextLine();
//                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    if (nome == m[i][1]) {
                    if (m[i][0].equals(nome)) {
//                        System.out.println(m[i][1]);
                        System.out.println(m[i][0]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Insira o CPF:");
                String cpf = c.next();
//                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    if (cpf == m[i][2]) {
                    if (m[i][1].equals(cpf)) {
//                        System.out.println(m[i][2]);
                        System.out.println(m[i][1]);

                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Insira o e-mail:");
                String email = e.next();
//                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    if (email == m[i][3]) {
                    if (m[i][2].equals(email)) {
//                        System.out.println(m[i][3]);
                        System.out.println(m[i][2]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Insira o telefone:");
                String telefone = t.next();
//                for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                    if (telefone == m[i][4]) {
                    if (m[i][3].equals(telefone)) {
//                        System.out.println(m[i][4]);
                        System.out.println(m[i][3]);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Sobre a parte "O programa deve informar caso não encontre nenhum cliente com o dado informado." não tem nada implementado, mas minha dica é usar uma lógica com flag.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: muito obrigada!!